# Specifying elements in different JQuery UI widget instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have a JQuery-created widget that generates input fields into divs that have prespecified and distinct ids. I'm having difficulty with form validation in the instance where I have two of these input field widgets on the same page. The first widget instance works fine, but the second instance seems to be responding to the input fields in the first instance and not its own input fields.

I realize that my code has the problem where I have elements with the same id -- not sure how best to get around this. Would appreciate help either in how to correctly identify the value of a specific input field or adding JQuery to my form creation code to create unique instances.

Here are the html containers:

```
    <div id="login">
    </div>

    <div id="otherDiv">
    </div>
```

Here's the JQuery widget:

```
            $.widget("custom.login", {
          // default options
          options: {
              action:null
          },

          // the constructor
          _create: function() {

             console.log(this.options.id);
             var html  = '';


             $(this.element).addClass("custom-login");

             html += '<form id="loginForm" action="' + (this.options.action||'') + '">'
             html += '<div id="container">';
             html += '<label id="loginTitleText">User Login</label>';
             html += '<div class="spacer"></div>';
             html += '<div class="field" id="loginDiv"><input type="text" placeholder="     Apple ID" id="loginUser"/></div>';
             html += '<div class="spacer"></div>';
             html += '<div class="field" id="passwordDiv"><input type="password" placeholder="     Password" id="loginPassword"/></div>';
             html += '<div class="spacer"></div>';
             html += '<div class="field" id="submitDiv"><input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Login to your account"/></div>';
             html += '</div>';
             html += '</form>';


             $(this.element).html(html);

             if(this.options.submit){
                 $('form', this.element).submit(this.options.submit);
             }

            this._refresh();
```

And here is the validation code:

```
        $("#login").login({submit:function(e){
            var x=document.forms["loginForm"]["loginUser"].value; 
            var y=document.forms["loginForm"]["loginPassword"].value; 
            if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y==""){  
                alert("Please fill out all fields");  
                return false;  
            } 

           $("#otherDiv").login({submit:function(e){
            var x=document.forms["loginForm"]["loginUser"].value; 
            var y=document.forms["loginForm"]["loginPassword"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y==""){  
                alert("Please fill out all fields");  
                return false;  
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: use classes instead of id

Comment: for repeating elements with ID. Then just reference everything from within parent using `find()` to isolate instances

Comment: So change the input ids to classes? Also I'm a little new to JQuery so a specific line of code using find() be hugely helpful. Thanks!